# How to use the screen menu bar with a mnemonic key combination on MacOS?

Tags: java, macos, swing

How to use the screen menu bar with a mnemonic key combination (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) instead of windows menu bar on MacOS?

Expected outcome (menu in the *screen* menu bar):

[image: expectation]

Actual outcome (menu in the *window* menu bar):

[image: reality]

Code:

```java
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;


class GUI extends JFrame {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GUI();
  }

  public GUI() {
    // Use the screen menu bar instead of the window menu bar.
    System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menu = new JMenu("File");
    JMenuItem menuItem1 = new JMenuItem("New");
    JMenuItem menuItem2 = new JMenuItem("Open");
    JMenuItem menuItem3 = new JMenuItem("Close");

    // Make the menu listens to <Ctrl> + <Alt> + <F> mnemonic key events.
    menu.setMnemonic('F');
    menu.add(menuItem1);
    menu.add(menuItem2);
    menu.add(menuItem3);
    menuBar.add(menu);
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    setSize(854, 480);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is impossible, there are no mnemonics to access the menu bar on macOS.

See a similar question on Super User: [How to select File menu in Mac, just like Alt + F in Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/504111/80304). Although the question is not Swing-specific, the answers highlight that this is impossible on macOS. Swing does its best to display the menu invoked by a mnemonic.